# updating column value depending on the same value of two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update, inner-join

I have a question regarding oracle sql. so what I am trying to is updating a column in one table according to same occurrence in another table. here is my sql

```
update master_drawing 
   set master_drawing.subcont_status = 'ASSIGNED' 
 where master_drawing.head_mark = master_drawing_assigned.head_mark
```

So in in both `MASTER_DRAWING` and `MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED` there are two exactly same column called `HEAD_MARK`. What im trying to do is like a check. If in those two tables there is a same value then update a column `SUBCONT_STATUS` with `'ASSIGNED'`

and the error message is:

> [Error] Execution (1: 103): ORA-00904: "MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED"."HEAD_MARK": invalid identifier

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
update master_drawing md
set md.subcont_status = "ASSIGNED"
where exists
(select 1 
 from master_drawing_assigned mda
 where md.head_mark = mda.head_mark)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE md 
SET md.subcont_status = 'ASSIGNED' 
FROM master_drawing md 
INNER JOIN master_drawing_assigned mda ON md.head_mark = mda.head_mark;
```